# Use Docusaurus for Commercial Project

Tags: docusaurus

Can we use Docusaurus to document our commercial project? We want to publish documentation with docusaurus on our public domain.

Regards,
Furkan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, it's MIT licensed.